# Duvidas com relação a Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

A estrutura é View -> Controller -> Model ?
Trabalho com 3 camadas mas não é MVC.
O que significa esse trecho ?

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

O que é ActionResult ?
Não tem Page_Load ?
Tô perdido.
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: Cara, tudo rsrs .. Tô começando a mexer agora, eu mexo com asp.net, 3 camadas e pra mim tá tudo diferente.

Comment: Se o post te ajudou, marque como resposta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC tem um conceito bem diferente do que você está acostumado com o webforms. Não existe conceito de página `.aspx`, ou sejam, uma URL não se refere mais a um determinado arquivo no site.

Quando você cria seu primeiro projeto. O Visual Studio cria para você um `HomeController`, uma classe herdada de `Controller`.

Esta classe tem um método chamado `Index` que retorna um `ActionView`.

Home/Index são o controller e o método padrão que são invocados caso você não solicite nada diferente (`//localhost:60253/Home/Index`, `//localhost:60253/Home`, `//localhost:60253` dão na mesma).

Estamos chamado o método Index do Controller Home.

Este método por sua vez, retorna uma View.

Por padrão, a view é a `index.cshtml` da pasta `/Views/Home`

ViewBag é uma coleção de valores que pode ser passado do controller para a View.

Exemplo:

```cs
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Mensagem = "Olá Mundo";
        return View();
    }
```

Permite você mostrar este conteúdo na sua página (index.cshtml)

```html
<body>
  Mensagem: @ViewBag.Mensagem
</body>
```

E

```cs
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

Mudaria o valor do atributo Title do ViewBag para "Index", que talvez mudaria o título da sua página caso seu cshtml tivesse este código:

```html
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Comment: entendi a sua resposta, porém as duvidas são muitas rs. Obrigado.

Comment: Estou vendo aqui também o tipo dos métodos são "ActionResult" o que é isso ?

Comment: ActionResult pode ser uma View (um html) ou um objeto Json, ou um JavaScript, um Stream... o método View() retorna um ViewResult, se mudar para Json(objeto) ele no lugar de um html retornaria um objeto Json